# "Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-module-resolver'" on a CI/CD pipeline

Tags: android, react-native, babeljs, babel-plugin-module-resolver

I set up a pipeline on a CI/CD (Azure Devops) to build my react native app, specifically for android.

Even though it builds correctly on my local mac (Mac OS 12.1), and assembles to a valid APK correctly, the same build step throws an error in the pipeline either using a Mac agent (MacOS 10.15 | 11), or Linux agents (Ubuntu 18.04 | 20.04).

This is the error:

```
> Task :app:bundleProductionReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-module-resolver'
Require stack:
- /Users/runner/work/1/s/babel.config.js
- /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/module-types.js
- /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/configuration.js
- /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
- /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
- /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/src/index.js
- /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js
- /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Worker.js
error index.js: Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-module-resolver'
Require stack:
- /Users/runner/work/1/s/babel.config.js
- /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/module-types.js
- /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/configuration.js
- /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
- /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
- /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/src/index.js
- /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js
- /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Worker.js
- /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/metro/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js.
- /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/metro/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.resolve (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:98:19)
    at module.exports (/Users/runner/work/1/s/babel.config.js:7:17)
    at readConfigJS (/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/configuration.js:227:15)
    at readConfigJS.next (<anonymous>)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/gensync-utils/async.js:25:3)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at evaluateSync (/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/gensync/index.js:251:28)
    at Function.sync (/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/gensync/index.js:89:14)
```

This is my `babel.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset', 'module:@babel/preset-typescript'],
    plugins: [
      [
        require.resolve('babel-plugin-module-resolver'),
        {
          root: ['./'],
          extensions: [
            '.ios.ts',
            '.android.ts',
            '.ts',
            '.ios.tsx',
            '.android.tsx',
            '.tsx',
            '.jsx',
            '.js',
            '.json',
          ],
          alias: {
            '@components': ['./src/components'],
            '@screens': ['./src/screens/'],
            '@shared': ['./src/shared/'],
            '@static': ['./src/static/'],
            '@stores': ['./src/stores/'],
            '@styles': ['./src/styles/'],
          },
        },
      ],
      [
        'module:react-native-dotenv',
        {
          moduleName: '@env',
          path: '.env',
          blacklist: null,
          whitelist: null,
          safe: true,
          allowUndefined: true,
        },
      ],
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin', // this plugin should be always at the end
    ],
  };
};
```

And my `package.json` (a reduced version in terms of dependencies for simplicity):

```json
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.2",
    // others not relevant
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.17.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.16.11",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.17.8",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "4.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.70.0",
    "react-native-dotenv": "3.3.1",
    // others not relevant
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "^17"
  }
}
```

I know that a [similar question has been already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70738939/react-native-macos-cannot-find-module-babel-plugin-module-resolver), but it doesn't have any response and it has an issue building the project even in a local machine. I only have this issue in the pipeline.

Comment: hey @hans, have you ever found a fix? I'm having the same error with a different library specified in babel config.